# auto sms not working on laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, sms, sms-gateway

I have purchased ultimate loan manager (built on laravel framework) from codecanyon, have set up this in cpanel and set up sms gateway (can send sms manually from backend) to borrower, however even if enabled, when adding repayment or payment, its not sending sms automatically as it should, whereas automatic email is working. Developer is being very unresponsive. If there's any solution or guidance how to proceed or where to look for what comes to mind, please share that. I would highly appreciate it.

Best Regards.

Comment: You probably have very low chances of getting an answer to this question on SO, mainly because that is a paid product and the CodeCanyon page indicates there have been 39 sales. So you'd have to be pretty lucky to find one of those 39 people active here and able to help. For the rest of us it's kind of impossible to help you out since we don't have access to that code base. So you're probably better off waiting for a response from the original developer.

Comment: I see, thank you for your response. I know that somewhat, however still wanted to check out if people with extensive prior knowledge on laravel have any suggestions perhaps where might lie problem in general, just in case, so that I could at least try looking into it from right direction. Trying to reach the developer but its really depressing when they respond but stop that after the purchase!

Comment: Unfortunately being knowledgeable in Laravel doesn't really help here, because it looks like a functionality issue with the product itself (since you said you can send sms messages from parts of the app). So you should probably try debugging the issue yourself by going step by step over the code that is responsible for doing that.